# create a specified quantity of loops in a query and create a report

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am wanting to create a query in access that asks how many times to run (How many logs do you want to run?). Then input the parameters for each query when it asks (Enter log number:) Then generate a report with the data on the logs that were entered. I am new to access and have created the query, but need to know how to make it loop in access, if possible, or if I need to study and write a VB module or SQL? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a query multiple times, use VBA. If you can rework your query so that you can do it all in one, then that's a better option.